# How to resolve volley Error , I am always finding error_response error?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am getting volley error every time but my data has been posted                   properly ,but in response, got volley error.

Please help me, I don't know why is it's happening?

```
       private void doSignUpTask(){
        String strName = nameET.getText().toString();
        String strHandicap = handicapET.getText().toString();
       // String strCountry = countryET.getText().toString();
        String strCODE = codeET.getText().toString();
        String strMobile = mobileET.getText().toString();
        String strEmail = emailET.getText().toString();
        String strPassword = passwordET.getText().toString();



        if (strName.length() == 0) {
            nameET.setError(getString(R.string.empty_name));
        }else if (strHandicap.length() == 0) {
            handicapET.setError(getString(R.string.empty_handicap));
        }else if (strCODE.length() == 0) {
            codeET.setError(getString(R.string.empty_code));
        }
        else if (strMobile.length() !=10 ) {
            mobileET.setError(getString(R.string.empty_mobile));
        }
        else if (strEmail.length() == 0) {
            emailET.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_email));
        } else if (!Utility.isEmailValid(strEmail)) {
            emailET.setError(getString(R.string.invalid_email));
        }else if (strPassword.length() == 0) {
            passwordET.setError(getString(R.string.password_empty));
        }
        else {
            nameET.setError(null);
            handicapET.setError(null);
            countryET.setError(null);
            codeET.setError(null);
            mobileET.setError(null);
            emailET.setError(null);
            passwordET.setError(null);
            //  phone_noView.setError(null);

            String deviceToken = refferenceWrapper.getDeviceInformationBean().getDeviceToken();

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;


            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.putOpt("email", strEmail);
                jsonObject.putOpt("password", strPassword);
                jsonObject.putOpt("fullname", strName);
                jsonObject.putOpt("handicap", strHandicap);

                jsonObject.putOpt("token", "");

                jsonObject.putOpt("device_token",deviceToken);
                jsonObject.putOpt("device_os","2");
                jsonObject.putOpt("country", country_name);
                jsonObject.putOpt("country_code",strCODE);
                jsonObject.putOpt("phone", strMobile);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();

            //RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, PUTTAPI.SIGN_UP_URL, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.e("Sign Up", "OnResponse =" + response.toString());
                    getSignUpResponse(response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something, wrong please try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            Log.e("Sign Up", "Url= " + PUTTAPI.SIGN_UP_URL + " PostObject = " + jsonObject.toString());
            //requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        }

    }
`
```

Comment: public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)

Comment: Post the Error logs.

Comment: this is not error method that will be called in case of error

Comment: i got every time error but my data is posting on server